# Android: Starting a new activity onListViewItem click

Tags: android, listview, android-intent, android-activity

I've an Activity containing a basic Listview. The functionality works as follows:

click a listview item -> get the listview item name -> pass the name with intent and start a new activity.

Everything is working except for the start of a new Activity. Its just not responsive and I cannot see why. I would really appreciate an extra pair of eyes to look over this.

```
listView = getListView();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, foodNames);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

listView.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parentView, View childView, int position, long id) {

        TextView tv  = (TextView) listView.getSelectedItem();
        String value = tv.getText().toString();

        Log.v("DEBUG","Name of item clicked" + value);

        Intent intent = new Intent(childView.getContext(), FoodItemActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("FoodName", value );
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parentView) {
    }
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I think you are missing line

```
startActivity(intent);
```

:-)

Comment: thanks Bertak, Ive added this line but it still doesnt call..Infact nothing inside the onItemSelected is called..

Comment: Hmm, did you try to use OnItemClickListener (setOnItemClickListener) instead of OnItemSelectedListener?

Comment: @BodhiByte  `lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
{
    @Override 
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,int position, long arg3)
    { 
               // start activity
    }
});`

Answer (score 0):

try it this way:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FoodItemActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("FoodName", value );
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

this will solve your question, and if still problem arises, then do confirm that all the child controls are `focusable=false` and `clickable=false`.